# Using the ISP assigned IP behind a router

Tags: networking, router, ip

This question is more on networking than on programming, hence I am asking here on superuser.
I am using google hangouts api and there I need to put my computer's ip in google developer console(currently app is in dev mode, hence we have to give the computer ip). At present my computer is behind a router which assigns me some dynamic ip.

I am trying to put the ip in google developer console that is assigned to me(ie. my router) via my isp (which I get via whatismyip.com)
But that is not working. I think it has something to do with port forwarding.

Currently I am on windows 8.1 so I am not sure what to do here to get it working.

Answer (score -1):

I think your Router Using NAT for Internet Sharing , you see internet but internet ( server of google ) can't see you correctly
you need have Valid ip , best way is say to your Provider assign static ip for you  ( Valid ip address ) or using a VPN server for get new IP (just assign to you)
you can use free solution seem torptoject

Comment: Thanks for answer. You are right that internet is not seeing me, but i am seeing internet. I can not tell my ISP to assign static ip as anyways my wifi router will assign me 192.168.*.* ip even if they give me static. I am not sure how will I use torproject for my case. They have a variety of services. Which one should I use?

Comment: Hi  I dont' know what your os ,  for install and configure tor see https://www.torproject.org/docs

Comment: you can config tor as daemon in your os and all of service using tor for connect to the internet  or  if you want a just surfing the web using torbrowser